# Idempotent Camel AWS2-S3 consumer not retrieving all files from bucket when deleteAfterRead is false

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-camel

I am using Camel AWS2-S3 with an idempotent consumer based on MemoryIdempotentRepository and try to read all files from an AWS/S3 bucket using Camel AWS2-S3 version 3.14.2. The intention is to keep the retrieved files in the bucket and therefore, deleteAfterRead is set to false.
When debugging my code I see consecutive polls retrieving always only one single file which is always the same. After the second poll this file is correctly considered a duplicate and ignored. In my DEBUG log I see "Ignoring duplicate message with id..." for this file.
However, although there are more files in my AWS/S3 bucket to retrieve, nothing happens until the polling delay initiating the next poll expires.
But then the next poll retrieves only the same already marked duplicate file and so on ...

What is needed to make the s3client keep on retrieving the next file in the bucket after ignoring the previous one.
All versions of Camel starting at 3.9.0 show the same behavior.

Has anyone run into the same problem and know how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Camel [AWS2 S3 Component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/aws2-s3-component.html) should work properly polling *AWS S3* bucket files as needed.

Having only one file polled should mean:

- Either you specified both `bucketName` and `fileName` when configuring your consumer which will resolve to polling the same file again and again
- Set the `maxMessagesPerPoll` to **1** while not deleting the processed messages which will as well resolve to polling the same file over and over
- Either set a `prefix` or `delimiter` configuration option matching a single file

You should start inspecting your endpoint configuration to see if any of these mis-configuration options apply.

On the other hand, to achieve idempotency you have one of two ways:

- Configure your consumer endpoint to `moveAfterRead` so that processed files are copied to a destination bucket avoiding them to be re-polled on next iteration (you need to configure the `destination` bucket). This solution would depend on your requirements and should be applicable only if you afford to have files in another bucket meaning no other component / service is relying on those files bien in the same source bucket
- Configure a [`IdempotentConsumer`](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.15.x/eips/idempotentConsumer-eip.html) backed by a repository of your choice in which case you can mark (and save) processed messages

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer.
I have indeed set maxMessagePerPoll to 1 and have also set the bucket name, but I did not set a fileName (consumer) endpoint param. The same endpoint DSL with the same params worked perfectly (all files were processed but not deleted from source bucket) with the previous version of Camel AWS-S3 (i.e. using it with Camel 3.8.0). Therefore, I was hoping to see the same behavior after the upgrade to AWS2-S3.

Comment: It seems that now after the upgrade I have to implement my own mechanics to iterate over the files in the bucket.
One idea is to use a Camel/AWS interaction to first obtain a list of all the file names stored in the bucket and then in subsequent Camel/AWS polling interactions (using the fileName (consumer) endpoint param) to pick all the files of interest one-by-one.

However, looking through the Camel AWS2-S3 endpoint spec and options it doesn't seem to be possible for a consumer to request such file list. 
Am I missing something?

Comment: Of course I could use the moveAfterRead option but this isn't allowed/possible in the actual usage scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with that and for me this is the best solution.
Put one route that checks if the file exists, and only if it exists call the second route

```
        from("timer:foo?period=5000")
    process(e -> {
    S3Client s3Client = // get your S3 client
    String bucketName = "com.xxx.input";
    String key = "tarjetas.csv";

    try { s3Client.headObject(HeadObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName).key(key).build());
           e.getIn().setBody(true);
        } catch (NoSuchKeyException ex) {
            e.getIn().setBody(false);
        }
    })
    .filter(body().isEqualTo(true))
    .to("direct:startMainRoute");

    from("direct:startMainRoute")
.pollEnrich("aws2-s3://com.xxx.input?amazonS3Client=#s3Client&fileName=tarjetas.csv&moveAfterRead=true&destinationBucket=com.ffresco.processed&delay=5000", 5000)
    .process(new TestProcessor())
    .split().tokenize("\n", 1).streaming()
    .log("Hello ${body}");
```